# How to allow a pods in Kubernetes access external docker container ip like mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, minikube, strapi

I wanted to deploy Strapi CMS to Kubernetes. On my local machine, I am trying to do this with Minikube. The structure of the project is MySQL in a different container outside of the cluster. I want to access the MySQL database from inside the cluster via this IP `172.17.0.2:3306`

The Database is outside of the cluster and lives in a docker container. But the Strapi project lives in a cluster of Kubernetes.

This is my deployment YAML file for doing the Kubernetes stuff:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cg-api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cg-api
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cg-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cg-api
          image: alirezahd/cg-api
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_HOST
              value: "172.17.0.2"
            - name: DATABASE_PORT
              value: "3306"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1337
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should expose MySQL port 3306 to outside of a container.
Assume host, on which Docker runs MySQL container, has 192.168.0.100 IP address. Then you can **telnet 192.168.0.100:3306** to be sure port is exposed and available.

Here is an example from [Dockers documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) :

```
docker run -p 192.168.0.100:3306:3306/tcp mysql-container-name bash
```

This binds port 3306 of the container to TCP port 3306 on 192.168.0.100 of the host machine.

Then you CMS can connect to it within minikube.

Try to deploy **dnsutils** under minikube. It provides network tools like nslookup, telnet etc. It very helps to resolve network issues within minikube. You can connect to it `sudo kubernetes exec -it dnsutils -n default -- bash`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the special minikube host to access your root machine. Assuming you have exposed the docker mysql container on your root machine using -p `3306:3306`

```
env:
  - name: DATABASE_HOST
    value: "host.minikube.internal"
```

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/#hostminikubeinternal
Looks like you need minikube v1.10+

Comment: host.docker.internal is enough